# Internal Server Error api/account/register

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting an internal server error when posting information back to register an individual account within Web API 2.  It happens on the `client.PostAsync`.   The api/account/register is not changed from what was created when creating teh Web API 2 project to use individual accounts.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<user>", "<pass>");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/<dev_site>/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var rbm = new RegisterBindingModel();
rbm.UserName = "<user>";
rbm.Password = "memememe";
rbm.ConfirmPassword = "memememe";

MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();.
HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<RegisterBindingModel>(rbm, jsonFormatter);

var resp = client.PostAsync("api/account/register", content).Result;


resp value = {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 14 Mar 2014 14:32:49 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 6065
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

The other thing I should mention is that this is coming from another .NET MVC application that is hooking into the Web API application.  I tried the exact same code, using the localhost and port number during debugging while in visual studio, and it worked completely fine within the homecontroller of the Web API project.  So it is throwing an internal server error when being called from the localhost outside of itself and the visual studio debugger but when inside of it, it is working as intended.

Comment: Your site is throwing an unhandled exception. It's going to be very difficult for anyone to help you without knowing what it is. Try attaching a debugger and identifying what's being thrown.

Comment: I put this up, initially for the most part, to see if there was anything glaring that was a mistake or missing with the code displayed.  As I said, I didn't make any modifications to how the account register portion was created by visual studio itself.  Also a way to see if anyone else ran into an internal server error on initial creation of a web API project and possibly had a solution I could try.

Comment: I also use the _memememe_ password :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error while running Azure myTodo sample code. The generic error is very frustrating. It turns out the error occurred at register method on server:

```
 IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

If you add a try/catch block around it and debug through it, it will tell you more details. In my case, I got the error message like:

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the
>   database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect
>   connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure
>   that the connection string is correct.

It is indeed a connection string problem, in my case.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what was wrong with your connection string? I am also getting an Internal Server Error when I reach that same identity result line in my code. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my case, one of the methods in API controller had public access modifier. I Changed it to private and Bang!!! Headache gone.